# Working around the Auth0 sample requirement to add history to react router

Tags: react-router, auth0

When following the [official Auth0 React SDK Quickstart guide](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login#read-the-user-profile), the code indicates the following:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* Don't forget to include the history module */}
      <Router history={history}>
        <header>
          <NavBar />
        </header>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact />
          <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, when trying to provide `history` to React Router, it gives me back an error! So why does Auth0 require that there, and is there a way around it?

Comment: can you explain what error you get back? I would not think this is a hard dependency but as a best practice. React navigation is different than the regular browser navigation. History package provides an implementation of  browser history and location API which improves react routing. https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md

Comment: In auth0 samples, history.js just returns the createBrowserHistory instance to be used in conjunction with react router. I found this post very useful to understand history API. http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html